# Are there any popular calendar framework for react native expo?

Tags: react-native, calendar, expo

Is there any popular/ easy-to-get-started frameworks for building calendar apps with React Native & Expo?

I am tryingt to build a mobile app that can display a list of the meeting records, supporting daily, weekly and monthly view. Full details of the meeting can be seen after clicking on each meeting record.
Details include i.e.: host name, participant name, discussion topic, objective, duration, date and time, and whether there is a follow-up meeting.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use `react-native-calendars` from Wix. This lib is no longer maintained so a little warning on it.